# jQuery on hover addClass

Tags: jquery, css

I know that with CSS, hovering over one elements can't change the properties of the elements that are nested inside of the given elements. So, I've been using jquery to change the properties of the elements that are nested inside of the given elements. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
?>   
   <tr>
       <td>Sample</td>
       <td>Text</td>
   </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $('tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).hover(function() {  
            $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");    
            $(this).css("background-color", "#0080ff");
        });

        $(this).mouseout(function() {   
            $(this).css("color", "#222222");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#f0f0f0"); 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that once I hover over the  tag, I'm triggering the mouseout action, and the font-color is being switched back to #222222, I want it to be so that as long as I'm hovered over the  tag or anything in it, the background color of the row is set #0080ff and the font-color is set to #ffffff. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't need javascript to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `mouseleave` as this will be triggered only when the mouse is completely outside the  element and not if on the elements children. So

```
$(this).mouseout(...)
```

should be

```
$(this).mouseleave(...)
```

Alternatively you can simply do

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $(this).hover(function() {  
        $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");    
        $(this).css("background-color", "#0080ff");
    }, function() {   
        $(this).css("color", "#222222");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f0f0f0"); 
    });
});
```

which actually binds the first function as the `mouseenter` handler and the second as the `mouseleave` handler.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I knew that the solutions was something very simple. I just didn't know what.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can target the elements inside the object being hovered using CSS.

In your case:

```
tr {
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

tr:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0080ff;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn8VJ/)

It looks like what your javascript is doing - changing CSS properties.
Am I interpreting your question correctly?

Comment: For more complex html structures where this approach doesn't work, remember that you can continue after the ':hover' part of the selector, as in: `tr:hover > td > span.foo {}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second param of `hover()`. Your code should look like:

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).hover(function() {  
            $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");    
            $(this).css("background-color", "#0080ff");
        }, function(){   
            $(this).css("color", "#222222");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#f0f0f0"); 
        });
});
```